# Extract float surrounded by white spaces within string

Tags: regex, matlab, octave

I have strings similar to this example:

```
str = '     area                                AMW1  =     93.3 m2 ';
```

And I would like to only extract the floating point number (possibly with sign "-") `93.3`. The float I like to extract is always surrouned by white spaces.

How can I do that?

I tried

```
s = regexp(str,'\d+\.?\d*','match')
```

However, it matches also the `1` and the `2`. Various other expressions I found do not work neither...

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try  `regexp(str,'\d+\.\d+','match')`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That seems to work, apart from the possible minus sign. How could I include that?

Comment: is the ordering of text in the string always the same:   whitespace-text-whitespace-text-whitespace-=-whitespaces-FLOATYOUWANT-whitespace-text-whitespace?

Comment: @NickJ, no, sorry. Could be anything, only the "single float surrounded by whitespace" is a constant. Of course I could use `strsplit` and somehow identify the number, but regex is cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```matlab
regexp(str,'-?\d+\.\d+','match')
```

Or, if you need to also match a `+`:

```matlab
regexp(str,'[-+]?\d+\.\d+','match')
```

If you need to match within whitespace boundaries only:

```matlab
regexp(str,'(?<!\S)[-+]?\d+\.\d+(?!\S)','match')
```

If the float value must be in between two whitespace chars:

```matlab
regexp(str,'(?<=\s)[-+]?\d+\.\d+(?=\s)','match')
```

*Details*

- `(?<=\s)` - right before the match, there must be a whitespace
- `(?<!\S)` - right before the match, there must be start of string, or a whitespace
- `[-+]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?!\S)` - right after, there must be the end of string or a whitespace
- `(?=\s)` - right after the match, there must be a whitespace.

And if you need to find both integer or floats, replace `\d+\.\d+` with `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
re.compile(r'(?<=\s)\d+(\.\d+)?(?=\s)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention in the question if/why you need to use `regexp`. If the string composition has a consistent pattern, you can just use `sscanf` or `textscan` to grab all of the non-whitespace elements instead of `regexp`.

```
>> str = '     area                                AMW1  =     93.3 m2 '
str =      area                                AMW1  =     93.3 m2
```

Using sscanf to read a predictably formatted string:

```
>> sscanf(str, " %s %s %s %f %s ")
ans =

    97.000
   114.000
   101.000
    97.000
    65.000
    77.000
    87.000
    49.000
    61.000
    93.300
   109.000
    50.000
```

(for mixed types, chars are stored as their numeric/ascii value in a numeric array)

Using `*` to ignore the elements you don't want

```
> sscanf(str, " %*s %*s %*s %f %*s ")
ans = 93.300
```

works with negatives also:

```
>> str = '     area                                AMW1  =     -93.3 m2 '
str =      area                                AMW1  =     -93.3 m2

>> sscanf(str, " %*s %*s %*s %f %*s ")
ans = -93.300
```

similarly, using textscan, which will store output in a cell array:

```
>> textscan(str, " %s %s %s %f %s ")
ans =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = area
  }

  [1,2] =
  {
    [1,1] = AMW1
  }

  [1,3] =
  {
    [1,1] = =
  }

  [1,4] = -93.300
  [1,5] =
  {
    [1,1] = m2
  }

}

>> textscan(str, " %*s %*s %*s %f %*s ")
ans =
{
  [1,1] = -93.300
}

>> cell2mat(textscan(s, " %*s %*s %*s %f %*s "))
ans = -93.300
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but there is no consistent pattern, why I did not mention it. So your approaches do not work in my case. That is why I asked a regex question, it is the cleanest way, but I struggle to define the patterns ;)